# JQuery UI Datepicker disable weekends but allow specific date?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am currently using the [datepicker](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and I make use of `beforeShowDay` and `noWeekends` to disable selection of weekends which works fine, however I would like to re-enable certain weekends for selection (e.g. Valentine's Day) as my shop will specially deliver for those days. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you will have to cheat a little over the UI DatePicker functionality, since you have to set manually the values that represent an active day of month.

First, take a look of the HTML structure of an active day:

```
<td data-year="2016" data-month="2" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay" class=" ">
<a href="#" class="ui-state-default">11</a>
</td>
```

And this is how an inactive day looks like:

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled ">
<span class="ui-state-default">12</span>
</td>
```

So, what you have to do is:

- Identify in the DOM the day of the month you want to activate. Ej, `$("table.ui-datepicker-calendar").find("td:contains(14)")`
- Remove the `ui-datepicker-unselectable` and `ui-state-disabled` classes using `removeClass()`
- Add the missing attributes: `data-year="2016" data-month="2" data-event="click" data-handler="selectDay"` using `attr()` method
- Convert the inner `<span>` to an `<a>` using `remove()` and `append()`
- And finally, you will have to also call `setDate` manually on the datePicker to set the desired date when the element is clicked.

It looks ugly and not so straightforward but it has worked for me, since there is nothing builtin in the DatePicker.